# Missing separator in makefile

Tags: make, makefile

I have next code in Makefile:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g

clean:
    rm -f ex1
```

When I run "make clean" I receive next error: Makefile:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Why? How I can fix it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have spaces where you should need a tab (and no: 4 spaces do not equal a tab).

This will show tabs (shown as `^I`) and spaces:

```
 cat -e -t -v {Makefile}
```

---

4th line:

```
1 CFLAGS=-Wall -g
2 
3 clean:
4     rm -f ex1
```

Remove the spaces in front of `rm` and make it a tab.

Comment: maybe add the link to https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html#Error-Messages to help rank the manual up in web search engines ;)